# How to Redirect Specific Page to Error page using HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess file like below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteCond ^ https://example.com/fernando/n-page.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/fernando/error.php [R,L]
```

What I am looking for if n-page.html, check if the user from mobile, if from mobile redirect to error page, if from desktop, nothing to do, if other page, I do not want do anything. I am trying Mobile checking thing is working fine, just unable to check if its n-page.html or not. Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^fernando/n-page\.html$ /fernando/error.php [R,L]
```

The above states: If the request is for `fernando/n-page.html` (no slash prefix) and has a mobile user-agent then redirect to `/fernando/error.php`. This is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html